# AngularJS ng-repeat: Change Array

Tags: jquery, regex, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-attributes

I want to change `categoryAlpha` into a different value (say, into `categoryBeta`) in the following HTML + AngularJS:

```html
<div ng-repeat="x in categoryAlpha | limitTo:quantity">
  <previews></previews>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Since ng-repeat isn't a normal attribute, I don't think I can change it through jQuery `attr()`. Is my only solution regex, or is there an Angular/jQuery method that can change the value `categoryAlpha`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: I want to change `categoryAlpha` into `categoryBeta` using JavaScript. Is there another way to do this other than regex?

Comment: I suspect there's a better way to get the ultimate result you seem to be going after. Why not change the contents of `categoryAlpha` rather than change which array is referenced?

Comment: What EdwardKnowles said. Do the two different "categories" have different data to display?

Comment: @erp yes, they have different data.

Comment: Under what circumstances does it need to change? Like does it need to reference a different array based on a certain value, and the other array if not?

Comment: @danny The content of `categoryAlpha` and `categoryBeta` are currently hard-coded with mockup content, so that option is unavailable. 
@erp The circumstance is dependent on the current querystring.

Comment: Right, but I think bgoscinski's answer below reflects the sort of thing I was thinking.  You're attacking an Angular problem with a jQuery solution, when there's a very Angular way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example create function which will return a collection for ng-repeat and assign it to scope. Something like:

```
// in your controller
$scope.getCategory = function getCategory() {
  return someCondition ? categoryAlpha : categoryBeta;
};
```

and then in your markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in getCategory() | limitTo:quantity">
  <previews></previews>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: Genius, I would have never thought of that. I will give it a go.